# Android HTTP Request issue

Tags: java, android

I am trying to fire a http request from an app i'm building in Andorid Studio, but seeing some bizzare behavoir

The following code, when ran, returns a HTTP/1.1 200, but the php scripts does not run. To check the the php script is correct, ive copied and pasted it into a browser and it runs absolutely fine

```
  HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.domain.com/script.php");

        try {
            // Add your data

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            mLastUpdateTimeTextView.setText(response.getStatusLine().toString());
            Log.d("Http Post Response:", response.toString());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Could any body please tell me why would i get a 200 ok response but the script not run?

Just to add I have got Internet Permissions set up in my manifest file

here is the logcat:

> 02-27 16:33:13.030  26409-26675/? I/ExchangeSyncSources﹕ [ NA
>   ][HttpClientLifeCycle] Created:1107382416 02-27 16:33:14.370 
>   26528-26528/? I/GHttpClientFactory﹕ Using the GMSCore's
>   GoogleHttpClient 02-27 16:33:14.590   9554-26702/?
>   I/GoogleURLConnFactory﹕ binding HttpService 02-27 16:33:14.600
>   9554-26702/? I/GoogleHttpClient﹕ Falling back to old
>   SSLCertificateSocketFactory 02-27 16:33:14.820  26409-26675/?
>   I/ExchangeSyncSources﹕ [ NA ][HttpClientLifeCycle] Closed: 1107382416
>   02-27 16:33:14.900  26409-26675/? I/BaseSyncSource﹕ [ NA
>   ][HttpClientLifeCycle,3] Created:1108133120 02-27 16:33:15.920 
>   26409-26675/? I/BaseSyncSource﹕ [ NA ][HttpClientLifeCycle,3] Closed:
>   1108133120 02-27 16:33:16.030  26409-26675/? I/BaseSyncSource﹕ [ NA
>   ][HttpClientLifeCycle,3] Created:1107653144 02-27 16:33:17.890 
>   26409-26675/? I/BaseSyncSource﹕ [ NA ][HttpClientLifeCycle,3] Closed:
>   1107653144 02-27 16:33:18.160  26409-26751/? I/BaseSyncSource﹕ [ NA
>   ][HttpClientLifeCycle,1] Created:1106603920 02-27 16:33:18.970 
>   26342-26342/com.example.matt.myapplication D/Http Post Response:﹕
>   org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@4201f0e8 02-27 16:33:19.050 
>   26409-26751/? I/BaseSyncSource﹕ [ NA ][HttpClientLifeCycle,1] Closed:
>   1106603920 02-27 16:33:19.180  26409-26757/? I/BaseSyncSource﹕ [ NA
>   ][HttpClientLifeCycle,2] Created:1106203584 02-27 16:33:19.930 
>   26409-26757/? I/BaseSyncSource﹕ [ NA ][HttpClientLifeCycle,2] Closed:
>   1106203584 02-27 16:33:20.150  26409-26773/? I/BaseSyncSource﹕ [ NA
>   ][HttpClientLifeCycle,4] Created:1108392040 02-27 16:33:21.040 
>   26409-26773/? I/BaseSyncSource﹕ [ NA ][HttpClientLifeCycle,4] Closed:
>   1108392040

Comment: What does get returned?

Comment: doesnt 200 mean the httpPost request was successfull, so the script been executed i guess. but for further info, we need more details ;)

Comment: edit the question with logcat included

Comment: are you sure you want a POST, and not a GET?

Answer (score 0):

I have some similiar method written a while ago, there are some small differences. As far as i remember, there is a difference between the 'HttpClient' and the 'DefaultHttpClient'.you can try it this way:

```
        DefaultHttpClient locationClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://www.domain.com/script.php");

        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = locationClient.execute(httpPost);
        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        }

        HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
        if (responseEntity != null) {

            // do something
        }
        else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Empty response");
        }
```

Comment: That doesnt seem to work either, its so fustrating as its only just start happening when I started to debug on my new phone

Answer (score 0):

So I got to confess, I have found the solution and it was to do with the url casing.

There was a capital letter in the url, which wasnt their in the file name on my server. This was causing the HTTP request to run the 404 error page.

The link worked in the browser, but not as a url path in the HTTP request in Java.

Now, I understand that this could be deemed as carless, but I would like to point out to that this could be a potential problem when making a HTTP request through Android